# Local basis of neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology

Show that the closed intervals $[−2^{ − n}, 2^{− n}], n \in \mathbb{N}$,  form a local basis of
neighbourhoods around $0$ in the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$

I have to prove:

If $\mathcal{B}(0)$is a base of neighborhoods of zero then, given any neighborhood of zero $V$, there is $U\in \mathcal{B}(0)$ such that $U\subset V$.

I do not know how to start

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $O$ is open and contains $0$ then for some open interval $0 \in  (a,b) \subseteq O$. Pick $n$ so large that $\frac{1}{2^n} < \min(|a|, b)$ and then $[-2^{-n}, 2^{-n}] \subseteq (a,b)$ and we're done.

Comment: why did you choose $ \frac{1}{2^n} < \min(|a|, b)$ ?

Comment: @Mathcristh80 because $\frac{1}{2^n}=2^{-n}$